# how to calculate days between two days including start date and end date

Tags: php, mysql, date

Consider two dates '2011-01-01' and '2011-01-02'.I want to calculate the number of days between these two dates.The result what I want is 2 days(i.e including both start and end date).I used several date functions in php and mysql,but all returns 1 as the answer.

```
$date11 = '2011-01-01';
$date22 = '2011-01-02';
    $dt1 = new DateTime($date11);
$dt2 = new DateTime($date22);
$diff = $dt2->diff($dt1);
echo $diff->format("%a");
```

Any solution in php or mysql would be grateful.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just add 1 to diff to account for the start day? Or take one day off the start day?

Comment: But there is only one day between them so just +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get `2` days for this interval you can just `+1` to the result, because none of the combinations of functions will give `2` days.

```
$date11 = strtotime($date11);
$date22 = strtotime($date22);
$diff = $date22 - $date11;
$diff_in_days = floor($diff/(60*60*24)) + 1;
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/150628)

Comment: `$datediff` is not set

Comment: I agree adding +1 is the solution to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use DateTime and DateInterval and do you add 1 day?

[DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php)
[DateInterval](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php)

```
<?php

    $d1 = new DateTime('2011-01-01');
    $d2 = new DateTime('2011-01-02');
    $d2->add(new DateInterval('24h'));

    $interval = $d2->diff($d1);

    $interval->format('%d Days');
    $interval->format('%h Hours');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in mysql:

```
 select abs(datediff('2011-01-01','2011-01-02'))+1 as difference;
+------------+
| difference |
+------------+
|          2 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

[datediff()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) returns the number of days between the two dates, [abs()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) makes sure we don't get negative values when switching first and second date and the final +1 because you wanted start and enddate to be included in the number.

Comment: No need to use mysql when PHP can do the tricke. OP may not even have a Mysql available.

Comment: which part of "Any solution in php **or mysql** would be grateful." in the OP's question was unclear?

Comment: Wanted to point out that introducing mysql (even if OP asked for it) is not desireable. It can also introduce bugs, if (for example) your PHP config specifies one timezone and Mysql is using another.

Comment: that may certainly be true, but I didn't suggest mixing php and mysql, this is a mysql solution only, hence the console output and no php code....nvm

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateDiff](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php). The online docs have this answer as the first example:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$datetime2->modify("+1 days");
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo $interval->format('%R%a days'); // output
```

Another way to do this:

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime('2009-10-11');
$datetime2 = new DateTime('2009-10-13');
$interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
$diff = $interval->days + 1;
echo $diff . " days.";
```

Comment: you may want to add the +1 offset to your solution to include both start and enddate as per OP's request. your example returns "+2 days" instead of 3